# Jquery nth-child issue with select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to following table

[image]

I have the button 'Add' that create a new row to my table

```
$(document).on('click','#add',function() {
    $('#table tr:last').after('<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">' +
        '<td> <select>' +
            '<option value="1">1</option>' +
            '<option value="2">2</option>' +
            '<option value="3">3</option>' +
            '<option value="4">4</option>' +
        '</select> </td>' +
        '<td style="display:none">A number</td>' +
        '<td>Test</td>' +
        '<td id="save">Save</td>' +
        '<td id="delete">Delete</td>' +
        '</tr>');
});
```

As you can see I have a dropdown list (1, 2, 3, 4) and a simple hidden text.

When I click to 'Save', I save the value of the dropdown, hide the dropdown, display the 'A number' field and replace it with the value of the dropdown.

I also change the 'Save' to 'Edit'

```
    $(document).on('click','#save',function() {
        this.id = "edit";
        this.innerHTML = "Edit";
        var qte = $(this).parent().find("td:first :selected").text();
        $(this).parent().find("td:first").hide();
        $(this).parent().find(":nth-child(2)").text(qte);
        $(this).parent().find(":nth-child(2)").show();
    });
```

When I want to 'Edit' again, I want to replace the quantity text with the dropdown list. So I hide the text and re-display the `<select>` tag

```
$(document).on('click','#edit',function() {
    this.id = "save";
    this.innerHTML = "Save";
    $(this).parent().find("td:first").show();
    $(this).parent().find(":nth-child(2)").hide();
});
```

Everything works well but the last line erase the `<option value="2">2</option>` of the `<select>`

I finish with this

[image]

I do not how to solve this. It may be not the best solution, I am open to any other way to get this working.

Comment: just a quick annotation: will the add button be clickable more than once? unique ids and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:nth-child(2)` will grab the 2nd child of everything within that parent. You might want to change it to `td:nth-child(2)`

As an aside, I would also change `td:first` to `td:first-child` as that is the natural CSS selector and is suggested to be quicker:

https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first").

Answer (score 0):

here this line creating problem :-

```
$(this).parent().find(":nth-child(2)").hide();
```

because it will hide everything which is at 2nd position that is why your desired tag is hided.

Better mention exatly what you want to hide..

in you case it is td so,

```
$(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(2)").show();
```